# Angular file upload size

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload

I use https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/ and I need to send file size to my backend server.

I don't find any solution, this is header that I receive:

```
{
  filename:'new02.png',
  headers:{
    'content-disposition':'form-data; name="files"; filename="new02.png"',
    'content-type':'image/png'
  }
}
```

Comment: On the demo page, i look the Json return by code, there's a length. function onAfterAddingFile return an object with a _file and a length

Comment: It not pass header like `Content-Length`...

Comment: You just have to send  your size length with the right property... You can send what you want at your backend server, you've a length so send it

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
files[0].type; //MIME type
files[0].size; //File size in bytes
};
```

Comment: I also use the same logic

Answer (score 0):

I'm using angular-file-upload too and a node.js server.

This is how I upload my file in my angular controller:

```
$scope.uploadInternationalFile = function(file) {
    if (file && file.length) {
        file.upload = Upload.upload({
            url: '/api/upload',
            method: 'POST',
            file: file
        });
        file.upload.then(function(response) {
            // file Sent
        });
    }
};
```

And I receive my file on my server like this with npm 'multer' package:

**module.js**

```
var privateStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
            callback(null, './files/');
        },
        filename: function(req, file, callback) {
            callback(null, file.originalname);
        }
    });

    var limits = {
        fieldNameSize: 100,
        fileSize:20000000,
        files: 1,
        fields: 5
    };

    var self = module.exports = {
        uploadPrivate: multer({
            storage:privateStorage,
            limits:limits
        }).single('file')
    };
```

And this is my API:

```
var fileUpload = require('module.js');
    app.post('/api/upload', function(req, res) {
        fileUpload.uploadPrivate(req, res, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                // There is an upload error
            }
            else {
                // Your file has been sent
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps.